# How to use accents in ajax to read data from database

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, search

I'm working on a list:
http://ranglista.farmeramagame.hu/kereso/search2.php

In the php file, I use meta tag, to handle the accents. But to show the result, I use ajax and if I write accents, like ö,ü,ő etc in the search field, it doesn't show anything.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var left = $('#box').position().left;
    var top = $('#box').position().top;

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value !=''){

        $('#search_result').show();
            $.post('search3.php',{value: value},function(data){
                $('#search_result').html(data);

            });

        } else{
        $('#search_result').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Is it possible somehow to make it work with accents?

Comment: How is search3.php implemented?

Comment: I hope it's not too impenetrable :)

Comment: I can read the parts I need to :) In the JS Ajax call, try: ` $.post('search3.php',{value: encodeURI(value)},function(data)` and in the PHP, when getting the POST value, do `$value = urldecode($_POST['value']);`. What this does is to convert the accented chars to URL encoding, and then in PHP convert back to raw string. Also, try `var_dump($_POST['value']);` and check the HTML source to debug the string as well.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't work.
In the firebug, I can see the posted value.
If I write 'á', the value is value=%C3%A1 instead of value=á.

Can I chanege it somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the information! Looks like this is utf8 encoding. I've added an answer for possibly solving the issue (utf8 decode the user input). However, there is one possible issue which is the value of the string from the DB. If you could do: `echo urlencode($row["nev"]);` for a row where the "nev" value has the 'á' character, then I can check to make sure the DB is using the correct string encoding as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to URI encode the string when it's being used in the Ajax to POST to string over.

In the JS, add encodeURI (just to be safe):

```
$.post('search3.php',{value: encodeURI(value)},function(data){
    $('#search_result').html(data);
});
```

Inside the PHP, you'll need to urldecode() the already encoded string, and it appears that the string is utf8 encoded.

Therefore, you'll want to do in the PHP:

```
$value = utf8_decode(urldecode($_POST['value']));
```

If this ends up working for you, you can then try removing the encodeURI() call in the JS and the urldecode() call in the PHP. (The utf8 handling is necessary, however.)